# Caps Locks light not showing

Tags: keyboard, capslock

I've installed Ubuntu on my MBP but when I press caps lock the green light on the caps lock button will not show. I can't tell when i have caps locks on because it won't turn on. What do i do to make the light show?

Comment: While I'm not sure why this would be happening so you will have to wait for another to help you fix the problem, in the mean time there is a program that you can use that will show the cap lock key as an indicator in the top panel.........you will need to add a ppa to use it. See [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/indicator-keylock-displays-keyboard.html) page for more info and instructions....

Answer (score 0):

[image]

im not sure about it but u can try !

Comment: I don't think that this will help to get the light to turn on, I know of no way to use those settings to do so.....also, it would be better to include *how* to get to that screen rather than just showing a random screen shot with no instructions.

Comment: I already have it set to default and it hasn't changed anything

Comment: next time when i insert any picture here, i will put instructions.